Volatile and Non-volatile fields in C#
Volatile fields in C#

A read of a volatile field is called a volatile read. A volatile read has “acquire semantics”; that is, it is guaranteed to occur prior to any references to memory that occur after it in the instruction sequence.


A write of a volatile field is called a volatile write. A volatile write has “release semantics”; that is, it is guaranteed to happen after any memory references prior to the write instruction in the instruction sequence.

Need help in understanding the above text from C# language specification on volatile fields. Particularly the "it is guaranteed to happen..." part.

The compiler is allowed to reorder the instructions of a program, provided that by doing so it won't affect the behavior of the program when running on a single thread. The volatile keyword restricts the compiler from reordering the instructions in certain ways, and if used correctly it makes possible to write multithreaded programs with predictable/correct behavior, without using the lock statement. Using correctly the volatile keyword, and writing correct lock-free code in general, is considered to be an extraordinarily difficult task.
